# Proof that $g(x):= \sup_{t\in[a,x]}f(t)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be continous. Let $g:(a,b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $$g(x):= \sup_{t\in[a,x]}f(t)$$

Show $g$ is also continuous.

Can someone quickly explain how this function is defined? I have trouble understanding it.

Comment: Note $g$ is just tracking the supremum of $f$ along $(a,b)$ as $x$ proceeds from $a$ to $b$

Comment: The intervals should be closed (at least on the left) for $g$ to be well defined.

Comment: Ah right sorry that was obvious....My brain is on gunk...  Can you give me a hint on how to prove it thou? Can you say if $t-b\ge 0$ then g is no longer continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: assuming the OP means $[a,b]$, (because the claim is false as stated (see comment below):

Let $x_0\in [a,b].$

If $\epsilon>0,$ then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ It follows that if $x_0<x,\ $ and $|x-x_0|<\delta,$

> $f(x)<f(x_0)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

and therefore, using the definition of the supremum,

> $g(x)\le f(x_0)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\le g(x_0)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Rightarrow g(x)-g(x_0)<\epsilon.$

Similarly, if $x<x_0$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ then $f(x_0)<f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and so

> $g(x_0)<g(x)+\epsilon.$

Comment: If $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=1/x$ then $g$ is not even well defined, let alone continuous.

Comment: @Momo: yes, of course. Thanks. The claim is true if we change $(a,b)$ to $[a,b].$

Comment: I think even $[a,b)$ works